# What's the difference between IDE encoding and project encoding?

Tags: intellij-idea, encoding

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, and there are `encoding` options including `IDE Encoding` and `Project Encoding`. Some blogs suggest to keep the two options same. So what's the difference between them? I changed one of the two and didn't find the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Project Encoding` is stored inside the project and is shared between developers working on the same project. New files in your project will get this encoding, except when overridden for specific files and directories.

`IDE Encoding` is the local encoding, stored within your IDE. When you create a new project, it gets this encoding. Files outside your project get this encoding too.

See also the online help about [file encodings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-encodings.html).